# Windows 10 GPT partition keeps getting MBR corrupted after restart

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, mbr, gpt

Recently my friend laptop got problem with the master boot record & keep showing that "no bootable devices can be found".

I though it's only a MBR problem but then I fixed the MBR & rebuildBCD with following commands

- `bootrect /fixmbr`
- `bootrect /rebuildbcd`
- `bootrect /fixboot` -> Output of this one giving "Access Denied"

I then can boot again into the windows. However, after restarting the problem comes up again.

I also try to delete all partitions and create all drives all over again, including formatting System Reserved drive.

After installing windows one more time, I got several successful reboot & then it comes up again. At this time I have no clues. (The system diagnosis from Dell showing green check on Hard Drive)

- ACHI enabled
- UEFI enabled
- Partition is GPT

Comment: But UEFI systems do not use a MBR.

Comment: @grawity: Now I know what you mean, I will follow up with this guide to fix the GPT partition table https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln300987/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-on-a-gpt-hdd-for-windows-7-8-81-and-10-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en

Comment: I rebuild the BCD store following the guide for Windows 10 but it still keeps happening